# Is it possible to stop windows from getting focus in i3 window manager? X11

Tags: xorg, focus

Is it possible to stop windows (applications) from getting focus?
For example when I launch discord, it steals focus multiple times, while I would like to be able to continue typing in my terminal, this is very annoying.
I use the X11 display manager and i3 window manager

Thanks Anyway

Answer (score 2):

I looked further in the i3 man, it can be found here
[focus on window activation](https://i3wm.org/docs/userguide.html#focus_on_window_activation)
and [no_focus](https://i3wm.org/docs/userguide.html#no_focus)

or simply add

```
no_focus [all]
focus_on_window_activation none
```

to your i3 config file
for me this didn't work at first because I had to update i3 for the all quantifier for no_focus.

updating i3 to the latest version on ubuntu is explained [here](https://i3wm.org/docs/repositories.html)